# C# Add body parameters to Request of a GET method

Tags: c#, get

So I'm being forced to use an API Endpoint that is get but also requires data in the body. I've tried various methods in c# but each time I keep getting the same result. Body Content is not allowed for the GET method.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can create an HTTPClient Request or WebRequest or anything that will allow me to hit their GET method with body parameters?

Comment: But why? Get should have no body. Why not use POST?

Comment: @Artur - I didn't create the call nor do I have any choice in the matter. It's a third party company and I'm being forced to use it. If it makes you guys feel any better, their internal staff cannot figure out how to use it. HAHA

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you're able to use GET request with a body. But in practice, it's VERY note recommended to do that. On this [site](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/http-get-delete-request-body-guidelines/) there is a detailed explanation of what I'm saying. Also, take a look at this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) topic. I don't want to copy good replies that's why I'm just attaching links to good and comprehensive results.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've been laboring under the impression that bodies were forbidden on GET requests for ages (largely because POSTMAN forbade them); it's nice to know that the spec has loosened the reigns a bit.